# Running Java, Python, Ruby and Perl programs in .NET

Tags: java, .net, python, ruby, perl

I've .NET framework 3.5 installed in my laptop. Just .NET alone, no Visual Studio. How can I run Java, Python, Ruby and Perl programs from the console?

Do I need to install something else also, for running these language files?

In case there is a need for something extra to be installed and after i have all of them, what are the commands that I need to type in the console to run these programs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you want to run programs in these languages inside the .NET platform? You'd need IronPython or IronRuby (I don't think anything like IronPerl exists).

If you want to run "normal" Python/Ruby/Perl/Java programs, then yes, you'll need to install a Python interpreter, a Ruby interpreter, a Perl interpreter and a Java VM.

Comment: PerlNET (Perl on .NET) exist

Answer (score 3):

Perl is a bit of a problem, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370078/why-is-there-no-ironperl-perl-for-net).  [IronRuby](http://ironruby.net/) and [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) cover those two languages.  For Java, I think you need Microsoft's [J#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vjsharp/default.aspx) (but I'm not entirely clear on the "visual vs not" situation for that product).

Answer (score 3):

None of those languages are supported natively with .NET.  You can try IronPython or IronRuby for those languages, but to run Java or Perl I think you'll actually need to download and install a Java VM and a perl interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

There's no practical common virtual machine or binary for the options you list. You will require a separate install for each of these (note that all are unrelated to .NET)